BackPress pop up option to just before closing the application in .NET Maui blazor
In my .NET Maui hybrid application using Blazor, I have a requirement: when a user attempts to navigate back or presses the back button in the mobile app, I need to display a confirmation popup asking if they want to close the application before proceeding to close the app. I tried below code in App.xaml.cs, but its showing pop up when opening the application again. I want to know which method to be called just before closing the application.
 public partial class App : Application
 {
     private IAudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
     private IAudioManager _audioManager;
     private NavigationManager NavigationManager;
     public bool isPlaying = true;
     public App(IAudioManager audioManager)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         MainPage = new MainPage();
         _audioManager = audioManager;
     }
     protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState? activationState)
     {
         Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

         window.Created += (s, e) =>
         {
             // Custom logic
         };

         window.Destroying += (s, e) =>
         {
             _audioPlayer.Stop();
         };

         window.Deactivated += (s, e) =>
         {
             if (_audioPlayer != null)
             {
                 _audioPlayer.Stop();
             }
         };
         
         window.Deactivated += Window_Deactivated;
        
         return window;

     
     }

  }

private async void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool canDeactivate = await ShowConfirmationDialog();
if (!canDeactivate)
{
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ShowConfirmationDialog()
    {
        bool canDeactivate = false;
        string message = "Do you want to leave the app?";
        var result = await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Confirmation", message, "Yes", "No");
        if (result)
        {
            canDeactivate = true;
        }
        return canDeactivate;
    }

I tried to do something like this in App.xaml.cs but with after closing the app it calling so that opening again my pop is showing.

Your problem is that the popup appears when the program is opened and closed? In addition, there is no code related to pop up in your code. Can you add some more detailed code?

@leon i have added the pop screen code

On Android platform, if the MainPage is your root page, you can try to set Popup when you click the back button by override the OnBackButtonPressed method in MainPage.xaml.cs:
protected override  bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        var leave = await DisplayAlert("asd", "dsadsa", "Yes", "No");
        if (leave)
        {
            Exit();
        }
    });
    return false;
}​

//This method is used to move the application to the background
public void Exit()
{
    bool exit = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.MoveTaskToBack(true);
    if (!exit)
    {
        var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMain);
        intent.AddCategory(Android.Content.Intent.CategoryHome);
        Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}


If you bind the window.Deactivated to the popup event, although the popup will be displayed when the back button is clicked, it will not prevent the program from entering the background, which will cause the popup to still appear when the app is opened again.

According to this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1118583/how-to-alerts-user-when-tap-exit-maui-android The following code inserted in the MainPage.xaml.cs file
protected  override   bool OnBackButtonPressed()  
   {  
        
       Task<bool> answer =  DisplayAlert("Question?", "Do you want to exit?", "Yes", "No");  
       answer.ContinueWith(task =>  
       {  
          if (task.Result)  
           {  
               Application.Current.Quit();  
           }  
       });         
       return true;  
   }  

will do as you asked. From my testing it works
